# How to Remove specific field from List

Tags: c#, list, generic-list, generic-collections

Class structure

```
 public class EmployeeDetails
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Exp { get; set; }
 }
```

List of employee details

```
Id Name       Exp
-- ---------  --------
1  Bill       2 years
2  John       5 years
3  Doug       1 years
```

I want to remove one field form list object like `Id`, like below **output**

```
Name       Exp
---------  --------
Bill       2 years
John       5 years
Doug       1 years
```

anyone have an idea how to do?
share with me
Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try:

```
var listWithoutCol = List.Select(x => new { x.Name , x.Exp}).ToList();
```

that will return a List with only the information of the fields **Name** and **Exp**...

Comment: can it possible when we make list object like  
`List<EmployeeDetails>= new List<EmployeeDetails>`

Comment: I don't understand your question in comment. Please specify more details.

Comment: hi  @XardasLord, 
when we initialize List<> at that time we remove specific field ?

Comment: Is it possible to reuse this selection in something like a method? I need to apply such filter in more than one case. I searched for it but ended up not so far...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the new list to have a concrete type objects instead of anonymous objects, you can define yourself a corresponding class without IDs:

```
public class EmployeeDetailsDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Exp { get; set; }
}
```

and use Select as:

```
var listWithoutIDs = List.Select(x => new EmployeeDetailsDTO{ Name = x.Name , Exp = x.Exp}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var employeeDetails = new List<EmployeDetails> { Id=1, Name="Peter", Exp="Two years" };   
var listWithoutId = employeeDetails.Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Exp}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonIgnore

```
 public class EmployeeDetails
 {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Exp { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: It's worth to mention that `JsonIgnore` was referencing `Newtonsoft.Json` and applicable for serialization scenario only.